# Django filter for multidimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, django, postgresql, multidimensional-array

In my `ModelX` I have such field:

```
foo = ArrayField(
    ArrayField(
        models.BooleanField()
    )
)
```

So it can be represented as array with 2 dimensions (e.g. `[[false,false,false],[true, false, true], [false, true, true]]`) I want to filter `ModelX` by this field this way. Imagine I have pattern matrix, and matrixes, that should be filtered, I need to count how many `true` items have equal `(row, column)` and if this number is greater, than some `n`, than it should be in result.

Example:

```
pattern = [[true, true, false],[false, false, false],[false, false, false]]
matrix = [[true, false, false],[true, false, true],[false, false, true]]
```

`matrix` has one overlap with `pattern` (in `(row, column) = (0,0)`). So if number of overlaps is set to 1, then it should be in result, if more than 1, then it should not be in result.

How can I implement this? Possibly with `.filter()` method.

I use PostgreSQL.

Comment: @e4c5 the question, that you provided is completely different, but answer is satisfying. Should I answer myself here (or may be you could) or just hit the "that solved my problem!" button?

Comment: Nested Arrays, yes, it's a duplicate. Don't use ArrayField just because it's tehre